# How do I disable the guest session?

Tags: lightdm, guest-session

How do I disable the guest session in Ubuntu 11.10 or higher? I don't want people to be able to use my computer without using a password to log in!

Comment: Can't you really think of any use case where one would want to disable the guest account? :P In my case, I'm the only one working on my PC so it doesn't make any sense for me to have it enabled. And I can think of other scenarios as well, but would go offtopic I guess :)

Comment: @mikewhatever - LightDM is a desktop manager, not a security manager. It as no business doing anything security and user related. Breaking the Unix security model should be enough. But if its not, then try searching for the security related bug reports. Folks keep accidentally breaking out of the Unity/LightDM sandbox (I filed at least two myself). What do you think an attacker could do?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Updated: 2016-Aug

## For Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (15.10 or later)

*Adapted from: [LightDM Ubuntu Wiki - Configuration](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM)*

- System provided configuration files in `/usr/share/lightdm/` are *not intended* to be user editable. Instead users should use: `/etc/lightdm/`
- Newer versions of LightDM (Ubuntu 15.10, or later) use `[Seat:*]` instead of `[SeatDefaults]`

Just run this (once) at terminal:

```
sudo sh -c 'printf "[Seat:*]\nallow-guest=false\n" >/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-no-guest.conf'
```

To undo (restore Guest option), *remove the file created*:

```
sudo rm /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-no-guest.conf
```

---

## For Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (up to 15.04)

*Adapted from: [Ubuntu Forums - lightdm config files location in 14.04](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2205637)*

Just run this (once) at terminal:

```
sudo sh -c 'printf "[SeatDefaults]\nallow-guest=false\n" >/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-no-guest.conf'
```

You will no longer have 'Guest' as login option, on your next login.

To undo (restore Guest option), *remove the file created*:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-no-guest.conf
```

---

## For Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (up to 13.10)

***Simplest method.***

Just run this (once) at terminal:

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -l false
```

You will no longer have 'Guest' as login option, on your next login.

- This simply appends `allow-guest=false` to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`.
- Should work from **11.10** onwards (since these use *LightDM* as well).

To undo (restore Guest option):

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -l true
```

Comment: This works for me on 13.10.

Comment: Worked for me on 14.04 beta 2. BTW, **SeatDefaults** is not a spelling mistake, don't change it to SetDefaults.

Comment: This method also works on Lubuntu 14.10. Guest account no longer accessible from login dialog.

Comment: This worked for me on Xubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. However, I’d correct this sentence: _“You will no longer have 'Guest' as login option, on your next login.”_ In fact, it remained until `lightdm` was restarted in my case.

Comment: On Xubuntu 14.04, this also worked when put in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/. (I expect it would work in this dir on most other systems, too.) This is useful for folks who use etckeeper or have other means of tracking or backing up their /etc changes.

Comment: I work on 12.04 LTS. The command 'sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -l true' gives 'option parsing failed: unknown option -1'.  Is it the letter l or the digit 1 in the command?

Comment: Its a lowercase letter 'L'. **Try copy/paste from the example given.**

Comment: Unnecessary quoting in the latest edit; please see https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html#disable Also: the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` folder is created automatically only in 16.04.1, so on previous versions it needs to be created before the command is run (`sudo mkdir /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d`).

Comment: Worked for 16.04, though have to **restart lightdm** to apply this change (note: this will also end your current session): `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm restart`

Comment: If you need to prevent 'guest' login, the overhead of simply re-starting the workstation/server is quite acceptable.

Answer (score 115):

> ***Only use this method if you are using Ubuntu Desktop. If you are using another flavour such as Xubuntu or Lubuntu please refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/169105/12435) instead.***

If you're using the default LightDM, edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` so that it looks like this:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
allow-guest=false
```

If you're using GDM (which was the default in previous Ubuntu releases), uninstall **gdm-guest-session**.

---

For Ubuntu **13.10** to **14.10**, the file has moved to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf`

For Ubuntu **14.10** or higher, the file has moved to
`/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf`

Comment: Answer seems to be out-of-date for 13.10

Comment: The instructions are the same for 13.10, except that the file has moved to: `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf`

Comment: @Andrew: It makes more sense to create a new file, e.g. `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-no-guest.conf`. The allow-guest option is not unity-greeter specific.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: You're right. Creating a new file also ensures that your changes won't be overwritten by a package upgrade.

Comment: @Andrew: Indeed. ;)

Comment: The new file must include `[SeatDefaults]` before `allow-guest=false`.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04:  I found the .conf here:
`/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf` . To locate the file I used `locate`

Comment: Works also in vivid (15.04), with config in `/usr/share`, too.

Answer (score 24):

Type this in the terminal

```
gksu gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

You will see the following:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
```

Add `allow-guest=false` to the end so your final result should look like:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
allow-guest=false
```

Save the document and quit the text editor.

Back in the Terminal, restart the display manager. (This will end the graphical login session, immediately quitting all programs running in it, so make sure your work--like any open documents--is saved first!)

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

With the graphical login session ended, you're returned to the login screen, where you'll notice that guest acount is disabled.

That's it--the guest account is no longer usable.

Answer (score 18):

You can do that using [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/).

To install it, use these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

After installing, navigate to **Tweaks** → **Login Settings** and switch off the "Guest account".

[image: ubuntu tweak login settings]

Comment: Nice find, and by the way, [Ubuntu Tweak will continue](http://blog.ubuntu-tweak.com/2012/10/22/thank-you-ubuntu-tweak-will-continue.html#more-1437).

Comment: wow! great to know, @mikewhatever! (that was fast, guess he missed us a lot...)

Answer (score 11):

Just run

```
gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add the following line

```
allow-guest=false
```

Then (this will immediately log you out, quitting any programs running in your graphical session, so save your work first):

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

Answer (score 4):

## How to disable this option in the future

I just ran into the same problem on my new trusty/14.04 installation. Also to my surprise I couldn't find the `lightdm.conf.d` folder inside `/etc/lightdm/` just `users.conf`.

### Investigation

```
$ find / -iname *lightdm* 2>/dev/null | grep -v /mnt | grep -v /media | grep -v /home
[...]
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[...]
```

Aha, there you are. What's in there?

```
$ ls -1 /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/
50-greeter-wrapper.conf
50-guest-wrapper.conf
50-ubuntu.conf
50-unity-greeter.conf
50-xserver-command.conf
```

Okay, what's in there?

```
$ cat /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-wrapper=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session
[SeatDefaults]
guest-wrapper=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
[SeatDefaults]
# Dump core
xserver-command=X -core
```

### Conclusion

We find a bunch of configuration files similar to the [INI format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ini_file) following the naming scheme of `50-${some-descriptive-name}.conf` and configuring keys for the section `[SeatDefaults]`.

**We're not going to edit any of these files** as these are meant to be managed by the package manager, but now we how we should add and manage our [custom configuration bits](https://plus.google.com/+ThorstenLeemhuis/posts/Ejf4f7HQ928) to `/etc`.

### Solution

Given the above, that lightdm is the display manager and the configuration files look like the above. The following solution should work:

1. Create the missing directories:

   ```
   $ sudo mkdir -p /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
   ```
2. Add a custom configuration file by running:

   ```
   $ sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-guest-session.conf
   ```

   and paste the following lines:

   ```
   [SeatDefaults]
   allow-guest=false
   ```

   Then save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) and close (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).
3. Now logout and switch to a virtual terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), then run:

   ```
   $ sudo service lightdm restart
   ```

   The guest session option should now be gone. If something is not working quite right you now know where the default configuration is stored and that you didn't change it.

### Further reading

- [Is there a list of all the possible configuration options for lightdm?](https://askubuntu.com/q/140471/40581)

Comment: Or, if you do not want to create an extra file put it into the existing /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

Answer (score 3):

For **Ubuntu 13.10**, add

```
allow-guest=false
```

to the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/10-ubuntu.conf`.

Answer (score 3):

### 13.04  and later

1. Execute this command in a terminal

   ```
    sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -l false
   ```
2. Reboot your machine or restart `lightdm` with the following command
   **(This will log you out immediately, save your data)**

   ```
    sudo restart lightdm
   ```

Apparently, it works in 13.10 (can't test myself, but there's a comment [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session#comment452416_169105)).

I'm using 13.04 and all this does it append `allow-guest=false` to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, but it might be different in 13.10.

Originally by [david6](https://askubuntu.com/users/34576/david6) from here: https://askubuntu.com/a/169105/176889

Comment: Thanks. It created a lightdm.conf file, the same as with you, with allow-guest=false in it.

Comment: You should also do `sudo restart lightdm` for the changes to take effect. Without that, the guest session will still be listed on the login screen when you log out.

Answer (score 2):

Change `allow-guest=true` to `'false'` in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

You can then either reboot or restart the service in the terminal:

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

Assuming you are using `lightdm` which is *standard* in 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

Install ubuntu-tweak, get to the tweak tab, turn off the guest button and reboot. That's it!

One may find the terminal easier, but in case the need to turn on the guest account arises then one would have to visit this page again and see the instructions (or rather undo). That's the advantage of the GUI thing... one remembers it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal

```
gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add the following line

```
allow-guest=false
```

Save and exit the file.

Comment: Also there was no gksudo (or gksu) in my Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Works fine in Ubuntu 14

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same case, the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` doesn't exist in UBUNTU 13.10.

I try to create the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file with this line `allow-guest=false`, and CRASH, the system does not start properly, only console mode...

I try to edit the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/10-ubuntu.conf`, and works properly.

Edit the file

```
sudo vim /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/10-ubuntu.conf
```

And enter the lines that you need

```
# to disable guest login
allow-guest=false
# to enable user login manually
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

And the last one, restart your system

```
sudo reboot
```

I think that this works fine if you restart only the ligthgdm

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```