# How do you disable/enable Guest Sessions in GUI?

Tags: 11.10, guest-session

I am wondering if there is a User Friendly (GUI) way to enable/disable the Guest Session.

If not, is there a way to allow logged in users to create Guest Sessions, but not from the login screen.

I am aware of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session):

> If you're using the default LightDM in Ubuntu 11.10, edit
>   /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf so that it looks like this:
>
> [SeatDefaults]
>   greeter-session=unity-greeter
>   user-session=ubuntu
>   allow-guest=false

Will this suit my fallback?

Comment: Note that a new question ([How to disable the guest account via the GUI?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/204211/how-to-disable-the-guest-account-via-the-gui)) also ask the same (with 12.10 instead of 11.10) and is closed as duplicate of [How do I disable the guest session?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not yet. LightDM is pretty new so there are still a few UI issues like that to iron out.