# How to disable the guest account via the GUI?

Tags: 12.10, gui, guest-session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the guest session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session)

I know you can [edit a configuration file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session) to disable the guest account, but is there any option to do that via the Ubuntu 12.10's GUI?

It's hard for me to believe that a simple on/off option wasn't implemented since the guest account was added to Ubuntu, and I'd be glad to find that option added as a feature to the 12.10 release.

Comment: It's always been pretty clear what this is asking, and the recent edit has made it even clearer. Let's please not close this question (unless it turns out to be a duplicate, of course). An easy, user-friendly way to disable the guest account would be welcomed by many novice users and people considering migrating to Ubuntu, whether or not they "really need" to disable it.