# Why can't I disable the Guest session?

Tags: 12.04, users, guest-session

I can't disable the Guest session for Ubuntu 12.04.

I tried to add `allow-guest=false` but it doesn't work.

Is there another way to disable it?

Comment: Have you tried the other methods mentioned in: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session

Comment: Are you sure you are using Lightdm with the Unity greeter (the default greeter)? Can you post all the contents of your file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method explained here:
[How to disable the guest account via the GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204211/how-to-disable-the-guest-account-via-the-gui)

Short version:
Install the ubuntu tweak from here: http://ubuntu-tweak.com/
Goto Ubuntu Tweak > Tweaks > Login Settings > Guest Account > OFF

Answer (score 1):

First you need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal. When you've opened the terminal you need to type: `sudo sh -c 'echo "allow-guest=false" >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'`
When you did that restart the computer and that's done ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the steps to disable the Guest account

http://dcageek.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-enable-disable-guest-account-in.html

Comment: Welcome! Usually on this site it's considered good practice to outline the entire solution and then provide the link afterwards as a reference; answers should stand alone, otherwise if the link rots for whatever (linked site is taken down, for instance) it no longer provides any help for a future user seeing it.