# How to disable the Guest account at the login of ubuntu 11.10

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the guest session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session)

whenever i boot up I get this GUEST account which i dont like can someone help me to remove this account.