# Disabling the guest account and session selection in lightdm

Tags: xubuntu, gdm, lightdm, session, guest-session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the guest session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session)

Is there a way to disable a guest account in (x,k,u,l)buntu's lightdm?
Also - is there a way to disable session selection in lightdm?

It would be convenient if it always logged in to an xubuntu session and not gnome or xfce.

Comment: Are you saying you want to remove the option of booting into any other DE entirely?

Comment: yes. this sometimes messes things up if done unintentionally. Like xfce and xubuntu and someone boots into xfce - this makes xubuntu lose some sesttings and some programs start twice.

Comment: I found that session desktop entries are in /usr/share/xsessions. So one can add .bak to disable them. Not sure if there are more correct ways.

Comment: That's the only way I know to do it.  Backing them up as opposed to deleting them outright like you did is definitely a good idea.