# Guest User Ubuntu 11.10 Guest User

Tags: 11.10, users, guest-session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the guest session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session)

How do I disable the guest user in ubuntu 11.10 
when using sudo edit lightdm.conf I am not able to open the file

Thanks