# Parental control of log in?

Tags: password, log

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the guest session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session)

I gave my daughter's user account on Ubuntu 11.10 a password that only I know so that I could control her use of the computer if needed.  She just logs in to the "Other" account on the log in page, defeating all my use of a password that only I know. Can anyone help with this problem?  Is there any way to delete the "Other" account? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You mean to say guest account? If yest, this follow this thread -http://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session

Comment: Hello, Sharon. Welcome to askubuntu.com.
The question pointed by @AmeyJah should be the solution for your question, please drop a comment if that is true so this question can be flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: It was asked and answered before (see link below):

http://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you mean you want to disable the guest account on your computer. You can do this by opening a terminal and typing `sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. A gedit(text editor) window will open. Find the portion of the document that starts with [SeatDefaults]. Find the line allow-guest and change it to `allow-guest=false`. Click save in gedit and close the terminal, then restart the computer. The guest option will no longer be at the login screen.