# How to eliminate guest session Ubuntu 12.04 

Tags: sudo, guest-session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the guest session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session)

Hello everyone I have a problem with the guest session ...

I turned on inadvertently and that started the problems!
How can I disable it because I do not need ...

I read on Google that typing on terminal

```
sudo gedit /etc/lighdm/lightdm.conf
```

I should be able to access the removal of the guest session and instead I get the message

```
sorry, try again . (sudo) password for antonio:
```

How do I do? Is something wrong? Thanks in advance and excuse my inexperience .....