# How do I disable guest session on Ubuntu 12.04LTS?

Tags: 12.04, security, lts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the guest session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session)

I don't really want anyone else being able to use my computer. How do I disable the guest session option that you get when being prompted to login?