# How do I disable the guest session in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: lightdm, 13.10

With Ubuntu 13.10 [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session) on how to disable the guest session no longer works because I think the lightdm config files have changed in Ubuntu 13.10.  I know you used to have to add the line `allow-guest=false` to the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` to disable the guest account but there is no file with this name. I see four config files in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` and I am not 100% on which one I edit for this.  I think it's the file `10-ubuntu.conf` but I don’t really know.