# Why are there guest-6lDH45Lx groups in /etc/group?

Tags: user-management

Found `guest-6lDH45Lx:132:` and `guest-MTiNKr:x:127:` groups in `/etc/group`.

Can anybody explain what these are and why they're lurking in my configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the names suggests, these are the group counterparts for [temporary guest account](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html) that `lightdm` has created. They are supposed to get cleaned up and removed after the session is done with but I could see that in a power-failure (for example) these could hang around. It might also be [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/1210550).

Assuming nobody is logged in as a guest, you can almost certainly delete these lines (and `/etc/passwd` counterparts) safely. There may also be temporary home directories lagging behind too.

You can also [disable the "guest session" functionality](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session) if you wish.