# Disable guest session in 14.04

Tags: guest-session

I want to disable guest session in ubuntu 14.04. I did that in 12.04 before, however I can't find `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` as in 12.04.

I think 14.04 might replace it with `/etc/lightdm/users.conf`, which has the following code:

> [UserAccounts]
>
> minimum-uid=500
>
> hidden-users=nobody nobody4 noaccess
>
> hidden-shells=/bin/false /usr/sbin/nologin

Should I change `hidden-users=` to `hidden-users=guest`?

Comment: Instructions for this is included in the 14.04 documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html#disable

Comment: @Jobin: Actually, that answer is not up to date for 14.04. So it makes sense to not see this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session/169105#169105) answer in the original question deals with the issue in 14.04.

Comment: @Jobin: Okej, okej. ;) (Not very easily found, though.)