# Disable Ubuntu Guest account

Tags: login, 14.10, guest-session

Is there any way to disable the Ubuntu guest account so as to prevent even someone on the guest account from logging into your computer?

I am on Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run this (once) at terminal:

```
sudo sh -c 'printf "[SeatDefaults]\nallow-guest=false\n" >/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-no-guest.conf'
```

You will no longer have 'Guest' as login option, on your next login.

To undo (restore Guest option), remove the file created:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-no-guest.conf
```

Duplicate: [How do I disable the guest session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session)

Comment: @Toroidal: The package which currently provides the guest session feature is lightdm, so I changed the affected package on that bug report accordingly. Even if it's not obvious that a GUI option would need to be added to lightdm, I'm pretty sure that the xorg package wouldn't have anything to do with it.