# I can get into my administer account on my Ubuntu without typing in the password how do I disable it?

Tags: security

I have a password on my Ubuntu computer, but if I just click the arrow next to login I can get into my account. I want to disable this, because my brothers have gone on and I don't want them to. Also, I want to disable my guest session part but I also do not know how to. Help please?

Answer (score 19):

Run command :

```
sudo gpasswd -d $USER nopasswdlogin
```

Next time it will ask password.

For disable guest session follow instructions explained at [How do I disable the guest session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session)

Comment: @Thatkid It would be nice if you could accept this answer since it worked for you. It would make it easier for others with the same problem to find the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Open **System Settings**

Then go to **User Accounts**

On top-right corner you will find **Unlock** button, press it and type your password to confirm your action.

From there turn off **Automatic Login**

For [disabling guest session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session) you will find an answer here.

Your problem will be solved.

Comment: No, this did not solve my problem. I already tried doing this, but thanks anyway. It will not automatically log in, but you just have to click login.